# Getting "cannot load Java class org.sikuli.script.Keys" while trying to run cucumber test using sikuli

Tags: java, macos, cucumber, jruby, sikuli

I'm trying to set up testing environment using sikuli+jruby+cucumber.
So I've installed latest JDK, Sikulix 1.1.1 , and latest JRuby, set up the cucumber test inspired by https://github.com/fozzie63/sikuli-jruby-cucumber
and when i'm trying to run test i get the following exception:

```
sikulitest EugeneMarrow$ cucumber 
missing class or uppercase package name (`org.sikuli.script.Keys'), caused by (NameError) cannot load Java class org.sikuli.script.Keys (NameError)
```

I've tried to: 
- downgrade to JDK 7 and switched back to JDK8;
- reinstall JRuby;
- use Sikulix Nightly Builds 1.1.2;

I'm running it on MacOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

I would trouble shoot my classpath if I saw an error like this. To me it is clear that you are missing something or referring to it with the wrong case.